# Silverlight ListBox Grouping

Tags: silverlight, listbox

I have problem while grouping in listbox.
Actually my table structure is as follows.

```
Emp_ID   EmpName  EmpParent_ID

1000002   Vivek   1000005
1000003   Rohit   1000005
1000005   Ajay    1000031
1000006   Sanjay  1000005
1000011   Hemant  -1
1000022   Amit    1000005
1000024   Aakash  1000006
1000027   Ameya   1000005
1000030   Ram     1000005
1000042   Arvind  -1
```

Now I want to group on `EmpParent_ID`. Output should be like this:

```
Ajay
  Vivek
  Rohit
  Sanjay
  Amit
  Ameya
  Ram
Sanjay
  Aakash
```

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight ListBox doesn't support grouping. You need some non-standard implementation or perhaps something like DataGrid.